# When did the first Dramatis Personae appear outside of theatre?

Tags: history-of-literature

According to the [Wikipedia article about Dramatis Personae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dramatis_person%C3%A6), Dramatis Personae began in plays and later moved into the other forms of literature. This led me to ask: When did Dramatis Personae first appear in a work of literature that was not a play?

Comment: I might have started something here ;)

Answer (score 2):

The first edition of [*Clarissa, or, the History of a Young Lady*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarissa) (1748) by Samuel Richardson begins with:

> A brief Account of the principal Characters throughout the Whole.
>
> Miss Clarissa Harlowe, *a young Lady of great Delicacy; Mistress of all the Accomplements, natural and acquired, that adorn the Sex; having the strictest Notions of filial Duty.*
>
> Robert Lovelace, *Esq; a Man of Birth and Fortune: Haughty, vindictive, humourously vain; equally intrepid and indefatigable in the Pursuit of his Pleasures—Making his Addresses to Miss* Clarissa Harlowe.
>
> James Harlowe, *Esq; the Father of Miss* Clarissa, *Miss* Arabella, *and Mr.* James Harlowe: *Despotic, absolute; and, when offended, not easily forgiving.* […]
>
> <sub>Samuel Richardson (1748). [*Clarissa, or, the History of a Young Lady*, volume 1, p. ix](https://archive.org/details/SamuelRichardson/page/n13). London: S. Richardson</sub>

This has longer character descriptions than a typical *dramatis personae*, but it is close, and Richardson’s next novel [*The History of Sir Charles Grandison*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_History_of_Sir_Charles_Grandison) (1754) is even closer:

> Names of the Principal Persons.
>
> MEN.
>   George Selby, *Esq*;
>   John Greville, *Esq*;
>   Richard Fenwick, *Esq*;
>   […]
>
> WOMEN.
>   *Miss* Harriet Byron.
>   *Mrs.* Shirley, *her Grandmother by the Mother’s Side*.
>   *Mrs.* Selby, *Sister to Miss* Byron’s *Father, and Wife of Mr.* Selby.
>   […]
>
> <sub>Samuel Richardson (1754). [*The History of Sir Charles Grandison*, volume 1, p. viii](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=sw0UAAAAQAAJ&pg=PR8). London: S. Richardson.</sub>

Later editions of *Clarissa* were revised to contain a list similar to that in *Charles Grandison*, for example the sixth edition (1768) has:

> Names of the Principal Persons
>
> Miss *Clarissa Harlowe*, A young Lady of great Beauty and Merit.
>   *Robert Lovelace*, Esq; Her Admirer.
>   *James Harlowe*, Esq; Father of Clarissa.
>   Mrs. *Harlowe*, His Lady.
>   […]
>
> <sub>Samuel Richardson (1768). [*Clarissa, or, the History of a Young Lady* (sixth edition), volume 1, p. xii](https://archive.org/details/clarissaorhisto00clargoog/page/n16). London: J. and F. Rivington.</sub>